# Olá! Estou tendo problemas com o menu mobile do meu site, após eu clicar em um link ele se recolhe, mas o ícone não volta ao estado normal. Obrigado

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Estou tendo problemas com o menu mobile do meu site, após eu clicar em um link (âncora) ele até se recolhe, mas o ícone do menu continua em forma de X.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
const hamburger_icon = hamburger.querySelector('span');
const mobile_menu = document.querySelector('.mobile-menu');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  hamburger_icon.innerText = hamburger_icon.innerText === 'menu' ?
    'close' :
    'menu';

  mobile_menu.classList.toggle('is-open');
})
$(".hamburger").click(function() {
  $(".mobile-menu").show();
});
$(".OpcoesMenu").click(function() {
  $(".mobile-menu").hide();
});
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">Eliseu Santos</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#showcase-container">Ínicio</a>
      <a href="#sobre-mim">Sobre Mim</a>
      <a href="#projetos">Projetos</a>
      <a href="#habilidades">Habilidades</a>
    </div>
    <button class="hamburger">
                <span class="material-icons">menu</span>
            </button>
  </nav>
  <div class="mobile-menu" id="opcoes-menu-mobile">
    <a href="#showcase-container" class="OpcoesMenu">Ínicio</a>
    <a href="#sobre-mim" class="OpcoesMenu">Sobre Mim</a>
    <a href="#projetos" class="OpcoesMenu">Projetos</a>
    <a href="#habilidades" class="OpcoesMenu">Habilidades</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -2):

Isso acontece porque a troca do ícone só ocorre quando se clica para abrir o menu. Quando o link é clicado, a única ação feita é esconder o menu ativo:

```
$(".OpcoesMenu").click(function() {
    $(".mobile-menu").hide();
});
```

Para que o ícone mude também, é necessário acrescentar mais essa linha ao *click*:

```
$(".OpcoesMenu").click(function() {
    $(".mobile-menu").hide();

    // faz o ícone voltar ao estado de fechado
    hamburger_icon.innerText = 'menu'
});
```